Using BigQuery Emulator Testcontainer with Apache Beam
We are using BigQuery Emulator with testcontainers in our project with java Spring applications which works nicely.
We also have a component that uses Apache Beam that connects to google BigQuery.
Is there a way to use this emulator with Apache Beam?
I couldn't get it to work because of the way that Apache Beam connects to BigQuery which is completely different from the way that you use BigQuery in a Spring application

Suggest posting in the discussions section https://github.com/goccy/bigquery-emulator/discussions or provide details in issues; there's one other post there about using Apache Beam + BQ emulator https://github.com/goccy/bigquery-emulator/issues/107
